# Best practice about empty belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Imagine the following situation:

I have a `dog` model and a `house` model. A dog can belong to a house, and a house can have many dogs, so:

```
Class Dog <  ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
end

Class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dogs
end
```

Now, imagine that I also want to create dogs that don't have a house. They don't belong to house. Can I still use that relationship structure and simply don't inform a `:house_id` when creating it?

Is there a better practice?

Obs.: I used this analogy to simplify my problem, but my real situation is: I have a model a user can generate instances of it. He can also create collections of those instances, but he can leave an instance outside a collection.

Comment: yes..you can leave `house_id` `null` and when you `@dog.house` it will return `nil` and so you can check it like `if @dog.house` and so on..

Comment: To make sure this works, in your database, the Dog table should not have the null part of `t.integer "house_id", :null => false`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think it is absolutely normal approach.

You can just leave `house_id` with `null` value in database for the models which don't belong to other.

Answer (score 366):

Be careful with this in Rails 5...

> #belongs_to is required by default
>
> From now on every Rails application will have a new configuration
> option `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default = true`, it
> will trigger a validation error when trying to save a model where
> `belongs_to` associations are not present.
>
> `config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default` can be changed to
> `false` and with this keep old Rails behavior or we can disable this
> validation on each `belongs_to` definition, just passing an additional
> option `optional: true` as follows:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author, optional: true
end
```

from: https://sipsandbits.com/2015/09/21/whats-new-in-rails-5/#belongs_toisrequiredbydefault

Comment: this is the answer to Rails 5 users

Comment: Spent 2 nights on this one... thanks guys. Can confirm optional: true does the trick. My use case was:

`class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team, optional: true
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end`