# How do I make my belongs_to field optional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, option-type, belongs-to

I’m using Rails 5.0.0.  I have this model

```
class Scenario < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :grading_rubric
  has_many :confidential_memo
end
```

but when I invoke my create method for the model, it fails

```
  def create
    @scenario = Scenario.new(scenario_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @scenario.save
        puts "saved successfully."
        format.html { redirect_to confidential_memo_path(@scenario), notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
      else
        puts "full messages: #{@scenario.errors.full_messages}"
        format.html { render action: "show" }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error I get is

```
full messages: ["Grading rubric must exist"]
```

How do I indicate that the belongs_to argument should be optional (that is, allowed to be null)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It used to be that you could just leave the value as `nil` and Rails was perfectly happy. However this was changed in Rails 5.

If you want the `belongs_to` to be optional, you simply have to pass `optional: true`:

```
belongs_to :grading_rubric, optional: true
```

You can find more info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775686/2526290)

Comment: Can you make that `optional: true` a dynamic expression based on model attributes? like the validations where you can append an `if: :condition` to the end. My use case is that i need it to be optional if a boolean flag is on or off